# How to split a wmv file in bytes implemented in C# language?

Tags: c#, file, split, byte, wmv

I have a wmv file whose size is 300 bytes. I want to split it into several bytes (example: (150 bytes each) or (3 100 bytes)). How do I implement this in C# Language?

Comment: Do you want those individual files to actually work, or are you planning on making something that combines them afterwards?

Comment: > 300 bytes  
Your're funny, man. 300 bytes of music/video, could be around umm 0.02 seconds long?

Comment: I want to split wmv file into 2 part: header and data. Then I encapsulate header part in a packet and data part in another packet to streaming to client

Comment: 300 bytes Your're funny, man. 300 bytes of music/video, could be around umm 0.02 seconds long?

Just example.

Comment: @HellDevil Are you a parrot? It is a very bad example.

Comment: Dude are you sure you don't mean 300 mega bytes? 300 bytes of video would be like a 1/60 frame flash, probably not even visible to the human eye

Comment: @HellDevil: You choose a very bad name, It is even bad to be heard!

Comment: ok 300 bytes's example. Actually i want to split a wmv file in byte to streaming. So how do i ???

Comment: @HellDevil: Just splitting the file in "header and data" doesn't make it a stream. How are you planning to stream the wmv?

Comment: Have you tried just sending it without explicit splitting, so the client decides when it can start playing? Some codecs can handle incomplete data very well.

Comment: @BrokenGlass and Floste : I'm using Windows Media Http Streaming Protocol.this protocol has 2 packets to send to client. #H packet contains header of wmv file and #D packet contains data part of wmv file. SO i must split it.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on whether you want the files to work or not. Splitting them in chunks is easy: Read them into a byte array, have a for loop that copies part of the array to a file of size CHUNK, without forgetting to copy the final bytes of the file. Splitting them in working files is different.

Comment: I want to split wmv file into 2 part: header and data. Then I encapsulate header part in a packet and data part in another packet to streaming to client. So how do i ???

Comment: @HellDevil: What are you hoping to do by splitting these components? You're incurring more server, packet, etc. overhead doing so.

Comment: @Brad Christie: i'm building a video streaming server using Windows Media Http Streaming Protocol. I must split a wmv file in to 2 part and encapsulate it in packets and send to client.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to just stream it without explicit splitting (the tcp stack will split it as it likes^^). If you have a good codec it will play it anyway. (Vlc can always plays the videos while downloading)

Comment: But i'm make a streaming in Windows Media Http Streaming Protocol. This protocol have 2 packets sent to client, #H packet contains header part of WMV file and #D packet contains data part.

Comment: Why in all the is holy would you try to create a streaming protocol?  Thats PhD work man.  Trust me when I say you arnt going to make it work.

Comment: @CrazyDart: it's my thesis." Building a streaming video server in windows media http streaming protocol"

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is, just use a streaming server and forget about writing a streaming protocol.  Thats crazy.  To split a file into byte segments you could use something like the code below.  Not thats untested, but it should be about 95% complete.

You should take a look at the proto spec if you havent already.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc251059(v=PROT.10).aspx  And if you have, and you asked this question, you dont stand an ice cubes chance in hell at making it work,

```
        int chunkSize = 300;
        var file = File.Open("c:\file.wmv", FileMode.Open);
        var numberOfChunks = (file.Length/chunkSize)+1;
        byte[][] fileBytes = new byte[numberOfChunks][];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChunks; i++)
        {
            int bytesToRead = chunkSize;
            if (i == numberOfChunks + 1)
            {
                bytesToRead = (int)(file.Length - (i * chunkSize));
            }
            fileBytes[i] = new byte[bytesToRead];
            file.Read(fileBytes[i], i * chunkSize, bytesToRead);
        }
```

Comment: Thank for supporting me.Actually I don't write a streaming protocol. I just writes a streaming server in Windows Media Http Streaming protocol. It's a protocol written by Microsoft.

Comment: I am not saying I could do it either... at least not without a bunch of research.  There are some projects out in the wild that use this, search for one thats open source and look for their code.